# TNG episode where aliens are testing on the crew

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I'm looking for an episode from Star Trek TNG where the crew is being tested by aliens. The only part I remember is near the end where Picard traps one on the bridge in a force field and says "we know about you now".

Comment: Welcome to the site. As for emailing you, this isn't a forum in the sense you may be used to, and it doesn't quite work that way. I'd recommend reading the [FAQ]

Comment: General reference: Googling for "star trek tng trap bridge force field know" brings up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegiance_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29 as hit #3.

Comment: @DVK Google is not general reference, and doing similar searches in Wikipedia doesn't find the episode

Comment: Holy cow!  I was just on my way to ask this, and then I find out I already did :)

Comment: @Izkata [Google is general reference](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/690/1359).

Comment: @Beofett That was back when General Reference was first created on the SE sites that have it.  We've since learned on SciFi.SE that Google cannot be General Reference for the topics on here largely because Google filters people's results based on their past searches.  Things like this that are easily googleable for me may not be easily googleable for others.

Comment: @Beofett Regardless, even "do a google search" isn't a single link to a standard reference; an expected Wikipedia or IMDB page is.  Those are the only two accepted General Reference sites on SciFi.SE - because you can give a single link that everyone can view.

Comment: Not to mention that you can't tell whether or not any random result is vetted and reliable; Wikipedia and IMDB are.

Comment: @Izkata - that's the point, Google POINTING to Wikipedia is a G.R. Neither of them by themselves is.

Comment: @DVK And this user may not be getting that result, because they may not be much of a Sci-Fi fan.  So it's not G.R.  That's the main point I'm trying to make.  Downvote if you feel they should have, but it isn't VTC-worthy.

Comment: @Izkata - Sorry. That's completely wrong on a technical level. I just re-did a search on a fresh Incognito Chrome window, with no Google user logged in. SAME results. And the same thing happend in a privacy-on Tor window. Neither could POSSIBLY be tailored to me (they are designed to be fully anonymous and non-identifyable)

Comment: @DVK Spend three months doing nothing but gardening searches, then get back to me ;)

Comment: @Izkata - do you understand how Tor or Chrome Incognito mode work? Google couldn't POSSIBLY KNOW about my search history. You can ask Gilles on chat or on SuperUser if you don't believe me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6351/discussion-between-izkata-and-dvk)

Comment: @Izkata Do you have a more recent Meta discussion that indicates what you are saying here (other than the one that says Wikia, by itself, is not a valid GR source)? If not, you should perhaps raise the issue again to get it clarified (and if we get a different consensus, the old meta discussion should be closed).

Comment: @DVK Google certainly does [personalize](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54041) search results, even in [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464). It certainly is possible that the OP did not find what they were looking for while searching for it. Giving them the benefit of the doubt, I am VTO.

Comment: @Beofett Look at the [last paragraph of Gilles's answer here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/956/2242), and what he links to.  They were posted a couple months after that one, which was still a year ago..

Comment: @Izkata That comment is tangential to the actual disucssion, and is a direct reference to the answer he gave on the older discussion, which is the lowest voted answer by a wide margin. His answer is more recent for "is Wikia by itself acceptable for G.R.", but tacking on a aside that is a repeat of his unpopular, older answer to a different question does not override the older question.

Comment: [Meta question to clarify Google as a GR source](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/is-the-answer-appearing-in-the-first-few-results-of-a-google-search-sufficient-b) posted.

Comment: Regardless of whether Google qualifies as a reference for closure purposes, this still fits well within General Reference by other sources.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegiance_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)), [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Allegiance_%28episode%29), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708675/), and [several other sources](http://tinyurl.com/a3qdxz7) have fairly detailed plot synopses that can easily be used (by someone willing to put in a relatively small amount of effort) to identify an episode by the details given.

Comment: since we can agree Google is not a great GR (this Q&A is a top search result, and the result noted in comments is no longer a result) can someone flag these comments for clean-up? they provide no value to this question, only wastes our collective time reading, etc. likewise, to the OP, if the answer provided (below) is the answer you were looking for can you please accept it as such? This is the correct episode for the quote you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

you're looking for [Allegiance](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Allegiance_%28episode%29):Season 3, episode 18.

[image]

Comment: yup this is the one.

Comment: mark the answer as correct please.